# Symfony async-aws-bundle installation error with composer require conflict

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I tried to install async-aws symfony bundle: https://async-aws.com/integration/symfony-bundle.html and I faced the below error when I try to run the `composer require async-aws/async-aws-bundle`

It seems to be conflicting with another package require but I could not find it yet.
I have tried to delete my vendor folder and composer.lock file and install the packages as well.

Appreciate if anyone can be any help to resolve this.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires async-aws/async-aws-bundle ^1.7 -> satisfiable by async-aws/async-aws-bundle[1.7.0].
> - async-aws/async-aws-bundle 1.7.0 requires symfony/config ^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.42, v5.0.0,
> ..., v5.4.9, v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.0] but these were not loaded, likely
> because it conflicts with another require.
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require async-aws/async-aws-bundle:*" to
> figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require
> async-aws/async-aws-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

My `composer.json` file,

```
{
"name": "",
"license": "",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-gmp": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-mongodb": "^1.8.1",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "async-aws/cognito-identity-provider": "^1.4",
    "async-aws/s3": "^1.12",
    "async-aws/simple-s3": "^1.1",
    "async-aws/sns": "^1.3",
    "async-aws/sqs": "^1.7",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.6.0",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.6",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
    "php-http/httplug-bundle": "^1.19",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^3.4",
    "symfony/intl": "^3.4",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-php81": "^1.23",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.4",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.33",
    "phpstan/phpstan-doctrine": "^0.12.33",
    "phpstan/phpstan-symfony": "^0.12.30",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "5.1.3",
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "AppBundle\\Util\\Helper\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "test": "./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit -d memory_limit=-1",
    "phpcs": "./vendor/bin/phpcs --extensions=php --standard=PSR2 ./src/*",
    "phpcbf": "./vendor/bin/phpcbf --extensions=php --standard=PSR2 ./src/*",
    "stan" : "./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --level=7 ./src"
},
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "process-timeout":0,
    "platform": {
        "ext-mongo": "1.6.16"
    },
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "branch-alias": null
}
```

}

Comment: What Nico Haase wrote, and also in the message: _"likely because it conflicts with another require."_ . You need to have a set of compatible dependencies before composer installs them.

Answer (score 1):

You are still using Symfony 3.4 according to this requirement:

`"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",`

Be warned that this version is out of support since Nov 2021, so please update your application to any later version of Symfony.

As even the very first released version of `async-aws/async-aws-bundle`  requires at least Symfony 4.4, you have no other chance if you really want to use the given package

Comment: Thank you for the response Nico. The thing is that this is a legacy application and I was trying to use the async-aws-bundle same as we use in our new application. Anyways, Yes, I realised that the package needs to be in an updated version of symfony or otherwise will have to stick with the aws-php-sdk.